# Making a face out of 2 Edge selections

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

It's maybe tricky to explain my problem, but I always find myself with this silly shape. I'm looking for a way where when I select 2 edges it creates a quad from it, is this possible? At the moment I extrude and wield the vertex in one corner, this is a smelly way of doing it cause then I might need to snap the vertex to X, Y or Z axis.

F addon makes a triangle, I'm still trying to tweak that where I can get better results, still a work in progress. I'm also trying to get Chat GTP to create an addon that might solve this problem.

Until I can come up with a solution, I'm asking if anyone out there will give me a few pointers in the right direction.

***If it helps I work a lot in Ortho views.***

So one idea is to the the 2 vertex points of the edges and somehow triangulate a 90degree position to make a a corner vertex to help bridge a face. (something like that lol)

Comment: With F2 addon, select the corner vertex.

Comment: select the edges, duplicate, R180 to rotate 180°, snap to the vertices

Comment: f2 Addon seems to extract a vertex? not really what I'm after.

Comment: No... try it. Select the corner vertex then F key

Comment: F key, not E key... and check if the F2 addon is activated.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq5sk.gif

Comment: @lemon I think you can write this as an answer

Comment: @moonboots, is it worth an answer? if you ask, why not...

Comment: @lemon not sure why it would not worth it?

Answer (score 5):

F2 addon is done for that. It is a standard addon, so just activate it.

For what we ask here, select the corner vertex, and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>, it will construct a losange face like so:

[image]

Comment: For myself it was just extruding the vertex :S but I think I was dragging instead of clicking... duh! Thanks